# Pre-build x-copy of .net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, build, msbuild

I have a asp.net web application(Along with solution) in a folder A at location C:/xxx/A/ 
I want that before each build operation, the copy of Whole folder A( Including Solution) should be copied to another location -  C:/yyyy/B.

Can anyone suggest me the way to do it if its possible ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)\ToCopy" "c:\destionation" /s /y
```

Should worke fine.